# Type-safe "schem based" *hierarchical* configuration read/write library for Java?

Tags: java, configuration

related to: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17359561/590335)

I want to have type safe front end to configuration files.

In the referred post [OWNER Project](https://github.com/lviggiano/owner) is suggested. this seems like a great solution - you just need provide the interface with annotations - and the frame word does the rest.

The problem is that the project doesn't support hierarchical configurations, and from the project site it appears it's not expected soon.

Any similar projects that do support this?

*EDIT*
What i'm looking for is something that will allow me to access a value like:

```
config.getHost();
```

instead of:

```
config.get("host");
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you have in mind exactly, but you can use YAML for configuration and you can "deserialize" the data into a data structure of your choice. i.e. the Java objects all type safe.  See [Snake YAML](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/)  IMHO YAML is the nicest for hierarchical data as text.

Comment: @OphirYoktan You can use YAML to build a data structure without needing annotations, or getters even.

Answer (score 1):

You could try IoC container. E.g. in guice it will be:

```
class MyClass
{
   @Inject @Named("host") String host;
   @Inject @Named("port") int port;
}
```

or with custom annotations:

```
class MyClass
{
   @Inject @Host String host;
   @Inject @Port int port;
}
```

Comment: sounds interesting. do you have a reference to a more detailed explanation of using guice for configuration files?

Comment: @OphirYoktan One mind-shifting change is to remove `config` form your beans, the configuration parameters are injected into a bean, not requested by a bean from a global `config` place, decoupling the dependency. There is a guice configuration Module to bind particular annotations with a values coming from different sources (environment variables, properties files, database, xml configs and so on). Start looking here: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions .

Comment: @OphirYoktan And think simpler. Why do you need hierarchical configuration? You could achieve it with simpler solutions. E.g. just naming parameters after package names such as `com.my.app.some.host`, `com.my.app.some.port`.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this is want you mean with type safe, but [commons-configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) supports multiple type safe get methods like

```
Double double = config.getDouble("number");
List<Object> buttons = config.getList("buttons.name");
```

commons-configuration also supports [hierarchical properties](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_xml.html#Hierarchical_properties)

Edit: Didn't see your edit, sorry. 
See Bozhos [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6005319/1430890) on the related question.

Comment: The referred answer that states it's impossible is on the same page with the reference to 'OWNER' that does 'the hard part'.